# Suppressing all labeling in pandas scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm producing a scatterplot matrix using the `scatter_matrix` function in `pandas.tools.plotting` and since I have a lot of variables the labels end up looking very messy.  Is there a way to suppress all the labels and perhaps even the tick marks?  Here is some code that shows essentially what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, scatter_matrix

n = 50
p = 15

cols = ['var_' + str(k) for k in range(p)]

data = DataFrame(np.random.randn(n, p), columns = cols)
scatter_matrix(data, diagonal = 'kde')
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please include your source code? You may want to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    sm = scatter_matrix(data, diagonal = 'kde')
    for subaxis in sm:
        for ax in subaxis:
            ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax.set_ylabel("")
            ax.set_xlabel("")
    pic = sm[0][0].get_figure()  
    pic.savefig("MyScatter.png")
```

Comment: Hmm, this gave me the error "Unkown property xticks."

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thank you!  Is there perhaps a less verbose way of coding this, though?